# Does it take multiple rolls to remove Persistent damage from Multiple sources?

Tags: stacking, pathfinder-2e

If you are under a persistent damage effect, you (typically) get a flat DC15 roll to remove it.  Various things can trigger this roll and/or change the DC, but it for sure comes right after you take the persistent damage.

Damage from multiple sources stacks only if it is of a different type.  That is, I could have 2 effects of persistent fire damage 2, and one of acid 1d6, and I would take 1d6 acid, and only 2 fire.

Does it take a separate roll to remove each instance of persistent damage?  Or can it all be removed with one successful check?

What if they are of a different type?  If I have two instances of persistent fire damage and one of acid, is that one, two, or three rolls to get me out of the hurt locker?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Each [Type] of Persistent damage is rolled for each turn.

The Persistent Damage [Condition and sidebar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=29) have all the details we need.

> [...] Instead of taking persistent damage immediately, you take it at the end of each of your turns as long as you have the condition, rolling any damage dice anew each time. After you take persistent damage, roll a DC 15 flat check to see if you recover from the persistent damage. If you succeed, **the condition ends.**
>
> You can be simultaneously affected by ***multiple persistent damage conditions* so long as they have different damage types.** If you would gain more than one persistent damage condition with the **same damage type, the higher amount of damage overrides the lower amount.** [...]

Takeaways:

- Each instance of Persistent Damage is one Condition
- Each Flat Check can remove "the Condition", so it's one check per instance of Persistent Damage
- You cannot have "two" instances of Persistent [Fire] Damage, only the larger applies

  - It does not specify if dice of damage or flat damage are prioritized, so how stacking rolled/flat Persistent Damage works will be up to the GM (I would personally rule that you roll the di(c)e, then take whichever damage is higher between that or the flat number, but one successful Check ends all of that [type])

So for your example of [Fire] 2, [Fire] 2, [Acid] 1d6, it is 1d6+2 damage and two checks at the end of your round.

Comment: I was asking how many flat rolls it takes to get rid of each condition when there are multiple conditions in effect.  Not how that damage stacks.  I think you answered that, but I am unclear.  Also - is this your interpretation.  Not that there is anything wrong with that, but It is helpful to know that, because again - the rulebook also seems unclear.

Comment: The combination of 'If you succeed, the condition ends.' (singular) and 'You can [have] multiple persistent damage conditions', seems a clear answer to me.

Comment: I can't say that it's not my interpretation... but Isaac has my points right. This is how it works RAW (and I believe RAI, if that matters). The only confusing part to me is that, per the text, you take damage then immediately roll to remove that Condition, but all Persistent damage is considered one "instance" of damage for purposes such as Dying. I changed my Header to be more clear.

Comment: 'but all Persistent damage is considered one "instance" of damage for purposes such as Dying.' Is a useful observation - thanks.